# Передача переменных в http обработчики

Tags: golang

Что ни день то вопрос.
В общем делал я как все:
Слушал порт, с nil в качестве хендлера

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(configuration.TLSPort, TLSFolderAdress+"Certificate.pem", TLSFolderAdress+"Key.pem", nil)
```

(на случай если не понятно про что)

Дальше обычное http.HandleFunc с паттерном строки и функцией обработчиком.
Когда нужно было взять что-то снаружи этой функции закидывал это в глобальные переменные (обьявленные вне функций) и брал просто используя такие переменные.

Но что-то подсказывает, что вообще так делать не надо, что вызывает вопрос:

Как передать в функцию обработчик что-то кроме http.ResponseWriter и *http.Request которые по дефолту передаёт http.HandleFunc и больше ничего передавать не хочет?

Чтобы отбросить глупые вопросы - у программы есть большая часть которая держит данные в памяти и работает с ними и сохранять их как файлы чтобы тут-же прочитать другой функцией - ну как-то звучит неразумно.

Comment: Вас интересуют параметры из _URL_ типа `/users/42/posts/123` или сущности типа соединения с БД?

Comment: Сущности типа соединения с бд или любые другие данные лежащие в переменных обьявленых в main а не в конкретной функции обработчике конкретной страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще глобальным *HTTP*-обработчиком пользоваться крайне
не рекомендую. Да и глобальным состоянием
в общем. Тем более, что пакет
`net/http` вам предоставляет всё необходимое для работы
с нормально инкапсулированными сущностями. Делаете свою
собственную сущность обработчика:

```golang
type APIHandler struct {
	db   DB
	repo DBRepo
	// …
}

func NewAPIHandler(db DB, repo DBRepo, /* … */) (h *APIHandler, err error) {
	// …
}

func (h *APIHandler) Users(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { /* … */ }
func (h *APIHandler) Posts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { /* … */ }
```

Делаете свой роутер и сервер (глобальный сервер
по умолчанию без таймаутов, если я правильно помню,
так что любой Вася Кулхацкер его вам положит) и запускаете:

```golang
h, err = NewAPIHandler(db, repo)
// Check err.

m := http.NewServeMux()
m.HandleFunc("/users", h.Users)
m.HandleFunc("/posts", h.Posts)

var srv = &http.Server{
	Addr:      ":8080",
	Handler:   m,
	TLSConfig: /* … */,

	IdleTimeout:       120 * time.Second,
	MaxHeaderBytes:    16 * 1024,
	ReadHeaderTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
	ReadTimeout:       10 * time.Second,
	WriteTimeout:      10 * time.Second,
}

err = srv.ListenAndServe()
// Check err.
```

Можете сделать отдельные обработчики для отдельных методов
*API*, а можете как здесь использовать
один. Пакет гибкий, всё зависит от сложности
и ширины вашего задания.

---

После уточнений из комментариев, стало понятно,
что ваш вопрос также и про спуск данных «вниз
по стеку». Сейчас для этого в основном
используется
[`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context#Context). Пример *middleware*:

```golang
func (h *APIHandler) Middleware(next http.Handler) (wrapped http.Handler) {
	return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
		var id, err = GetID()
		// Check err.
		r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctxKeyID, id))
		next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
	})
}
```

```golang
m.Handle("/users", h.Middleware(http.HandlerFunc(h.Users)))
```

Пример использования контекста в обработчике:

```golang
func (h *APIHandler) Users(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
	var ctx = r.Context()
	var v = ctx.Value(ctxKeyID)

	var id, ok = v.(ID)
	if !ok {
		// Ошибка: либо неверен тип, либо значения нету вообще.
	}

	// …
}
```

О ключах для контекста
я [писал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891417/1892060)
на английском *StackOverflow*.

Comment: А более *человеческие* варианты существуют?

Comment: Это очень странный вопрос.  Что значит «человеческие»?  Это ещё простой вариант, без *middleware*, данных контекста, слоя кеширования, и так далее.  У любого, кто не пришёл с голого *PHP,* проблем быть не должно.  Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы, я готов расширить ответ.

Comment: Это если что не претензия к вам, просто вопрос. Я же выше и писал, что интересует передача вот тех самых данных из middleware. Оно там в отдельной гоурутине что-то сделало и положило в переменную и в файл, если в результате вычислений что-то меняется - оно снова попадает в переменную и снова сохраняется этой гоурутиной в файл. Сейчас вот эта переменная лежит в глобальной зоне видимости, а хотелось бы в main и передавать дальше как аргумент функции. Вот это без написания очередного не-стокового сервера-роутера возможно как-то?

Comment: Если мой ответ вышел грубым, прошу прощения, просто вопрос был странный для меня лично :-) .  Добавил пример с *middleware,* который прокидывает значение вниз.  Если это тоже не то, пожалуйста, добавьте в свой вопрос [минимальный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) код, показывающий, что у вас сейчас.